# how to put array form data in update query and remove array to string conversion from update query

Tags: php, arrays

when using foreach loop its inner foreach loop two time more runs examples:-assumes 
first foreach loop runs two time and second inner foreach loop runs one time now  happened here is that first foreach loop runs two time and inner foreach also runs two times , due to this resign i am unable to get id and edit data in the database.

input array in this form :-

```
Array ( [reps_value] => Array ( [0] => q1 [1] => q2 ) [reps_percent] => Array ( [0] => e1 [1] => e2 ) [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )
```

i am getting null value in my query

```
UPDATE dev_prescription2 SET `reps_percent`= '',`reps_value`= '' WHERE id= ''
```

In update query value not showing and array to string conversion showing some times

```
 public function prescriptionUpdateData($data) {
        //print_r("Print");
       print_r($data);
      foreach( $data as $data1){ 
   print_r( $reps_percent = $data1['reps_percent']);
   print_r($id = $data1['id']);
    print_r($reps_value = $data1['reps_value']);

     $result = $this->db->query("UPDATE dev_prescription2 SET `reps_percent`= '".$reps_percent."',`reps_value`= '".$reps_value."'
              WHERE 
               id= '".$id."'");

            }

            $insertid = $this->db->insert_id();
                if ($result > 0) {
                    return TRUE;
                } else {
                   return $this->db->_error_message();
                }

         }
```

my html format is :-

```
<?php foreach ($data['prescription_week1'] as $key=>$value){
        $location[]  = ($value['reps_value']); 
        $location[] =   ($value['reps_percent']);
        $location[] =   ($value['id']);
         }  
//        print_r($location);
         ?>  


i am using array in html format
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdval="20" sdnum="1033;"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><input style="width:90%" type="text"  name="reps_value[]" id="reps_value" value="<?php echo $location[0] ?>" class="languages_list" /></font></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdnum="1033;0;0.0%"><font face="Agency-Roman" size="1" color="#FF0000"><input style="width:90%" type="text"  name="reps_percent[]" id="reps_value" value="<?php echo $location[1] ?>" /><input style="width:90%" type="hidden"  name="id[]" id="id"  value="<?php echo $location[2] ?>"/></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdval="20" sdnum="1033;"><font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000"><input style="width:90%" type="text" name="reps_value[]" id="reps_value" value="<?php echo $location[3] ?>"/></font></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdnum="1033;0;0.0%"><font face="Agency-Roman" size="1" color="#FF0000"><input style="width:90%" type="text"  name="reps_percent[]" id="reps_value" value="<?php echo $location[4] ?>" /><input style="width:90%" type="hidden"  name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $location[5] ?>"/></font></td>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
```

my databse table is :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z00df.png)

```
this is my controller part:-
public function prescriptionUpdate() {

        $response = $response = $this->Godspeed->prescriptionUpdateData($_POST);

            }
```

Comment: Hello welcome to stack overflow, I am looking trough your question but I don't see a secondary inner loop that you have mentioned.

Comment: yes, sir i have edit this question and  second inner loop of foreach loop remove  because i think this is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Hey Developer here is your problem and solution:

Your array is this:

```
Array ( 
    [reps_value] => Array ( 
                        [0] => q1 
                        [1] => q2 
                   ) 
    [reps_percent] => Array ( 
                          [0] => e1 
                          [1] => e2 
                      ) 
    [id] => Array ( 
                [0] => 1 
                [1] => 2 ) 
)
```

As you can see here your `$data` is array with three keys that contain arrays with in them.

So your loop should be like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'reps_value'){
       // Do something with reps_value arrey
    }

    if($key == 'reps_percent'){
       // Do something with reps_percent array
    }

    if($key == 'id'){
        $idArray = $value;
        // Here you can loop again over the ids
        // your current $id is blank because its an array and not an integer
    }
}
```

You may want to create function to break up your foreach loop so that it doesn't get too complicated with 3 if statments.

Eg:

You can create functions for each key

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'reps_value'){
           reps_value($value);
        }

        if($key == 'reps_percent'){
           reps_percent($value);
        }

        if($key == 'id'){
            ids($value);
        }
    }

public function reps_value($array){
  // Loop over the array and do your functionality
}

public function reps_percent($array){
  // Loop over the array and do your functionality
}

public function ids($array){
  // Loop over the array and do your functionality
}
```

Let me know how this works or if you have any questions that in regards to my proposed solution.

Good luck with the project and welcome to StackOverflow

**update per OP request:**

Here is solution in same function just like you had it:

```
public function prescriptionUpdateData($data) {

$reps_values = null;
$reps_percents = null;
$ids = null;

foreach( $data as $key => $values){ 

        if($key == 'reps_value'){
           $reps_values = $values;
        }

        if($key == 'reps_percent'){
           $reps_percents = $values;
        }

        if($key == 'id'){
            $ids = $values;
        }

}

$arrayLength = count($ids);

if($arrayLength == $reps_values && $arrayLength == $reps_percents){

    for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++){
        $result = $this->db->query("UPDATE dev_prescription2 SET `reps_percent`= '".$reps_percents[$i]."',`reps_value`= '".$reps_values[$i]."' WHERE id= '".$ids[$i]."'");

        if ($result > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return $this->db->_error_message();
        }

    }

}else{
 // Missmatched arrays
}

// $insertid = $this->db->insert_id(); this line is not required as you are doing the update


}
```

Comment: Sir, can u make this solution in my question as customize to my question  its unable to put code